# How to use modal view as a menu and segue the background view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a few view controllers with segues presenting modally to a menu view controller. I also have a few buttons set up on the menu view. How do I perform a segue between the view controller (that is behind the modal) and a new view controller immediately after pressing a button on the menu and dismissing the modal? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `prepareForSegue` method between your view controllers

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentier" {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath!

           //take your actions here
        }
    }
```

hope that helped